# What does Hilbert's 90 theorem tell us about Galois fixed points in projective space?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, galois-cohomology

Consider the following statement:

> If $K\subseteq L$ is a Galois extension of fields with Galois group $G$ and $x \in \mathbb{P}^n(L)$ is such that $\sigma(x)=x$ for all $\sigma\in G$, then $x \in \mathbb{P}^n(K)$.

Here are two proofs of it (taking for granted the fundamental fact of Galois theory that if $z\in L$ satisfies $\sigma(z)=z$ for all $\sigma\in G$ then $z\in K$):

- Proof **S** (for “Sophisticated”): let $X \in L^{n+1}$ lift $x$ (i.e., a system of homogeneous coordinates for $x$).  Then $\sigma(x)=x$ translates to $\sigma(X) = c_\sigma\, X$ for some (uniquely defined) $c_\sigma \in L^\times$, which satisfies $c_{\tau\sigma} = \tau(c_\sigma)\,c_\tau$, meaning $c \colon G \to L^\times$ is a $1$-cocycle.  So by [Noether's generalization of Hilbert's theorem 90 (NH90)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Theorem_90#Cohomology), it is a coboundary, meaning there exists $b\in L^\times$ such that $c_\sigma = \sigma(b)/b$ for all $\sigma$.  But then $\sigma(X/b) = X/b$ for all $\sigma$, so $X/b \in K^{n+1}$, which represents the same $x$, so $x \in \mathbb{P}^n(K)$ as claimed.
- Proof **T** (for “Trivial”): write $x = (x_0:\cdots:x_n)$ and let $i$ be the smallest index such that $x_i\neq 0$.  Then dividing by $x_i$ we can write $x = (0:\cdots:0:1:y_{i+1}:\cdots:y_n)$ where $y_j = x_j/x_i$.  The fact that $\sigma(x)=x$ gives $\sigma(y_j)=y_j$ for all $j$, so $y_j \in K$, proving $x\in\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ as claimed.  (*Equivalently*: the decomposition $\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{A}^n \uplus \mathbb{A}^{n-1} \uplus \cdots \uplus \mathbb{A}^0$, where $\mathbb{A}^{n-i}$ corresponds to the vanishing of the first $i$ coordinates and the nonvanishing of the next, works both for $L$ and $K$, and is stable under $G$ so we are reduced to the statement for $\mathbb{A}^{n-i}$, which is clear.)

I do hope both proofs are correct (which is why I took the trouble to write them in such excruciating details), but here's the thing: for a long time I was so blinded by the fact that proof **S** seemed to be “[The Right Thing](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/Right-Thing.html)” to do that I completely missed proof **T** (at some point I even told some students that “the same fact for $\mathbb{P}^n$ as for $\mathbb{A}^n$ depends on a fairly deep result sometimes known as ‘Hilbert's theorem 90’”, which is really embarrassing), and realizing its existence threw me into disarray.  I mean, this statement really looks like NH90 was *meant* to prove it, and it's not supposed to be a trivial fact!  So how can we have such a trivial proof?  What am I missing?

To make my question a little less vague and perhaps a bit more productive, let me ask:

**Question:** Does proof **S** have added value over **T**?  Does it perhaps tell us more or does it work in a more general context¹?  Or conversely, can we explain what makes the **T** shortcut away from NH90 possible in this context and not in others?

1. Other than trivially reproducing NH90 by saying something like “any $\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$-torsor is trivial” (however, it might help answer the question to explain why the torsor which appears in the statement at the top of this question is “trivially trivial”, if I dare call it that).

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about the group cohomology question, but I will point out that the same arguments show: Let $V \subset L^n$ be an $L$-vector space with $\sigma(V) = V$ for all $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(L/K)$, then $V$ has a basis in $K^n$. I use this when I prove Artin's lemma in setting up Galois theory https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386626/intuition-for-artins-lemma/3636638#3636638

Comment: Both arguments are versions of the fact that etale (or even fppf) torsors for $\mathbb{G}_m$ are Zariski locally trivial.  One advantage of the first argument is that it works for other situations, e.g., every $K$-point of $\textbf{PGL}_n$ lifts to a $K$-point of $\textbf{GL}_n$ (but not necessarily to a $K$-point of $\textbf{SL}_n$ since $\mu_n$-torsors are typically not Zariski locally trivial).

Comment: David’s comment is an instance of Galois descent, which in turn has a proof using the scaling of coefficients to make a coefficient $1$ that is just like the OP’s proof $\mathbf T$. See equation (2.2) simplified to the case where $a_n = 1$ in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf. The application to showing certain subspaces of $L^n$ have a basis in $K^n$ is Theorem 3.2.

Comment: I'd say that @JasonStarr's example of $GL_n \to PGL_n$ isn't really another situation: $GL_n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ and $PGL_n$ is its preimage in $\mathbb{P}^{n^2-1}$, so the claim follows by argument <b>T</b> for $\mathbb{P}^{n^2-1}$. I'm not sure how to make this precise, but I wonder if there is any $\mathbb{G}_m$ principal bundle which isn't induced from affine space over projective space like this.

Comment: I advise to read Grothendieck's comments on Hilbert's Theorem 90 and descent in FGA.  Certainly there *do* exist $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsors that do not arise via pullback from the Serre twisting sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$, since there are non-globally generated invertible sheaves whose dual is also not globally generated.  Perhaps a more significant example arises from the method of lifting to the universal torsor to understand rational points (in those cases where the Picard group scheme is a split lattice).